# Can I print Latin and Cyrillic text and graphics on an Epson LQ-350 dot-matrix printer from my Mac?

Tags: big-sur, printing, cups

I'm considering buying the [Epson LQ-350 dot-matrix printer](https://www.amazon.de/-/en/Epson-LQ-350-Matrix-Printer-Needles/dp/B00AC3S0ES/ref=pb_allspark_dp_sims_pao_desktop_session_based_2/262-8602704-0911120?pd_rd_w=YyXxY&pf_rd_p=8d810135-3da6-4ad8-9713-67849c17dccd&pf_rd_r=7Q4YC776Q9QJ4T2XN01Z&pd_rd_r=6db62a0d-7cba-42b4-b5da-7cdaa460af25&pd_rd_wg=1Mcjn&pd_rd_i=B00AC3S0ES&psc=1). I want to use it on my Mac in order to print

1. Latin text (ideally with [Umlauts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diaeresis_(diacritic))),
2. Cyrillic (Russian) text, and
3. (optionally) graphics (such as PDF versions of HTML pages).

Note: By "Latin text" and "Cyrillic text" I mean sending files to the printer in pure text mode which it would print using one of its built-in fonts.

**Will I be able to do items 1, 2, and 3 above, if connect that printer to my Mac (running MacOS BigSur 11.2.3)?**

My answer: I will be able to print Latin text, but without Umlauts. Printing German texts, as well as items 2 and 3 are not possible without writing my own driver.

How I came to this conclusion:

1. Somewhere I read that Mac supports all the printers which support [CUPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUPS).
2. According to [openprinting.org](http://www.openprinting.org/printer/Epson/Epson-LQ-350),

> Printer supports direct text printing with the 'us-ascii' charset.

However that openprinting.org page talks about using this printer on Linux, and not on Mac.

Comment: Is there some reason this printer without Mac drivers is important to your needs?

Comment: @TomGewecke Yes. It seems that for low-quality, mostly text-only printouts this printer is the cheapest option. You pay around 250 Euros for the printer itself, and then around 7 Euros for the [ribbon cartridge](https://www.amazon.de/-/en/Epson-C13S015633-SIDM-RIBBON-LQ-350/dp/B00B98BI8K/ref=pd_vtp_1/262-8602704-0911120?pd_rd_w=BsIvb&pf_rd_p=4e0c7b51-e41d-4568-8470-6e0da61f6c1d&pf_rd_r=WQ0XFKCYA7G49P707N1D&pd_rd_r=7328cf46-3954-4680-99f8-d81836510ba6&pd_rd_wg=c2ScY&pd_rd_i=B00B98BI8K&psc=1) with which you can print 2.5 million characters.

Comment: My laser multi-function printer is fully supported by my OS, can scan, copy & fax too; cost less than your ancient dot-matrix & produces beautiful type [&/or graphics] to about 7 million characters per cartridge. I think your economy is false. The only possible reason to want a dot-matrix in this day & age is if you are making NCR sets ['carbon copy' paper] They produce barely-legible text even under ideal conditions. My last one lasted 10 years before the cartridges needed replacing - at which time I just bought a new printer instead.

Comment: @Tetsujin This does not answer the question.

Comment: That's why it's a comment. Answers go in the answer space below. This is a frame-challenge.

Comment: Hello. I don't know the answer to your question but this YouTube video shows someone buying one of those printers and trying it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UV6OSheyQzk . Maybe you can write to that YouTuber and ask if he can try with a Mac?

Comment: According to an Amazon page it said it would be compatible with Windows 2000. Then it is not impossible that the printer may be using a "general" or already existing  driver (mostly because I don't think they would write new drivers for such old OS) then it may be compatible with macOS because macOS is compatibly with a lot of old printers (says my old experience).